# Scala 3 "a match type could not be fully reduced" with literal types

Tags: scala, scala-3, singleton-type, match-types

I'm learning Scala 3, and I was intrigued by match types and literal types.

I'd like to write a function that takes one of a few literal types, and returns a particular type as a function of which literal type was passed in.

Here's a fairly minimal example of what I'm trying to do:

```scala
type TestMatchType[T] = T match
  case "String1" => Int
  case "String2" => String

def testMatchType[T](input: T): TestMatchType[T] =
  input match
    case "String1": "String1" => 1
    case "String2": "String2" => "Two"

val string1Output: Int = testMatchType("String1")
```

In words:

- "I'd like to write a function, `testMatchType`, which takes an argument whose type is either the type literal `"String1"`, or the type literal `"String2"`. If an argument with type `"String1"` is passed, the function should return an `Int`. If an argument with type `"String2"` is passed, the function should return a `String`. If an argument is passed whose type is not one of these type literals, a compile-time error is produced."

However, when I try to compile the above code, I get the following error:

```
1 |val string1Output: Int = testMatchType("String1")
  |                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |               Found:    TestMatchType[String]
  |               Required: Int
  |
  |               Note: a match type could not be fully reduced:
  |
  |                 trying to reduce  TestMatchType[String]
  |                 failed since selector  String
  |                 does not match  case ("String1" : String) => Int
  |                 and cannot be shown to be disjoint from it either.
  |                 Therefore, reduction cannot advance to the remaining case
  |
  |                   case ("String2" : String) => String
```

I'm trying to grok that error message. I'm struggling to understand the line "`selector  String  does not match  case ("String1" : String) => Int`". I would love some advice if there's a way to make this work.

Thank you!

Comment: **N.B.**  If, instead of type literals on the left-hand side of the type match, I use ordinary types (e.g. `Int` and `String`), I think I was able to get things to work. So maybe there's some limitations with type matches for type literals? Just an observation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to use `"foo": "foo"`, just use `_: "foo"`.

However, the error happens because `T` will not be inferred as a singleton type, so the return type will never be `Int` or `String` either, it'll remain `TestMatchType[String]`. You'll either have to use `T <: Singleton` or use `input.type` as an argument to `TestMatchType` (I prefer the latter).

```scala
def testMatchType[T](input: T): TestMatchType[input.type] =
  input match
    case _: "String1" => 1
    case _: "String2" => "Two"
```

[Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/aat2qACmQGC42nyVqv4brQ)

Comment: Wow this is AWESOME, thank you for sharing! I had no idea about the `Singleton` type (not to be confused with the concept of singleton types). It looks like [SIP-23](https://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/42.type.html) talks about this more, so I will take a read! (Although I agree with you -- your proposed solution is more elegant than using the `Singleton` type.)

Comment: @MichaelTingley Glad to help! The preference of `.type` over `Singleton` is about more than elegancy: Martin Odersky himself referred to it as a [hack](https://contributors.scala-lang.org/t/abstract-type-projections-for-singleton-types/5181/3?u=ysthakur). It's quite possible that `T <: Singleton` will be dropped in favor of other mechanisms in the future, whereas `.type` will remain, so I went with that.